# bgiframe appears in front of jquery modal dialog's overlay in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, jquery-dialog, bgiframe

When I look at jquery ui's demo modal dialog (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) in IE6 the bgiframe is appearing on top of the background overlay.  So instead of seeing a black/gray stripe pattern, there is just a white background covering the page with the word "false" in the upper left corner.  Is bgiframe broken with the latest version of jqueryui?  Is there a quick way to repair this problem with bgiframe?  If not, is there a plugin that hides selects when a modal dialog is shown?  The ie6 z-index issue with selects is the reason I was using bgiframe in the first place.

Comment: It looks like this may only be happening in sp2.  Any idea what sp2 market share is?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this answer
http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2009/02/19/jquery-bgiframe-and-ie6-z-order-hacks/